# Stop `-[tableView reloadData]` when touched on screen

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

In my app, there is a `-[tableView reloadData]` method, that is invoked periodically. While the data is being loaded, I have the `userInteractionEnabled` set to NO. I want the TableView to stop loading Data if A click has occurred on screen and re-enable UserInteraction, but I want the loaded cells to be unaffected and the `-cellDidSelectRowAtIndexPath` to remain intact. How can I do this?

Comment: Ask clearly Sidharth

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  // called on finger up as we are moving
{
//Stop ur periodic method Or stop timer if u have set
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView     // called when scroll view grinds to a halt{

//Re-start ur periodic method 
 }
```

implement ur tableview scrollview delegate methods